# AmazonKinesisClient constructor is deprecated

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I want to create Kinesis stream using Java. So I followed aws doc(URL:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-using-sdk-java-create-stream.html). According to that, 1st of all i have to create Kinesis Streams Client. I try it by given code which is:

> client = new AmazonKinesisClient();

I'm using eclipse with aws toolkit for eclipse,java version "1.8.0_131" in Windows environment. Above code give me this error:

> The constructor AmazonKinesisClient() is deprecated

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecation warnings is not an error, it's just the compiler warning you that something has been deprecated and may be removed in the future - your code will still work even if you're using `new AmazonKinesisClient()`, until that constructor is removed from the SDK sometime in the future.

The new way of creating clients in the AWS SDK is to use the builder API like this:

```
final AmazonKinesisClientBuilder builder = AmazonKinesisClient.builder();
final AmazonKinesis client = builder.build();
```

This way, you can use `builder` to customize the client, like setting region or using STS credentials.

If you just want to get an instance using the default settings you can do:

```
final AmazonKinesis client = AmazonKinesisClient.builder().build();
```

Comment: Note that while you used to instantiate and use an instance of `AmazonKinesisClient` you know use the builder to create an instance of `AmazonKinesis`.  This class name semantically weak IMO.